# Vue JS 2.0 Child Component Mounted Callback

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am making a form built of Vue JS components. I have the following components tree (each component contains the child below it ex. User Registration Form has the Form component as its direct child).

1. User Registration Vue Component
2. Form Vue Component
3. Input Vue Component
4. Input Option Component

After all of the components have full rendered I need to run a function in the User Registration. I tried putting it in the mounted function in the User Registration Vue Component but it runs before the Option Components have completed their mounted function.

I read here: https://medium.com/@brockreece/vue-parent-and-child-lifecycle-hooks-5d6236bd561f that this should not happen and that the child component should be completely mounted before the running the parent mounted function, in this situation the User Registration Vue Component.

I have about 100 components total including the Form, Inputs and all of the options.

I can only run this desired code in the User Registration Vue Component after everything has fully rendered and loaded. I tried using the jQuery(document).ready function but I have inconsistent results (sometimes the document is ready before the forms have fully mounted).

Any recommendations?

Comment: Instead of describing your code, showing it would help a lot more. Is the is the function you are trying to run in mounted async perhaps?

Comment: @ippi it is not async. The code I am trying to run looks like this const field_1 = this.form.getFieldByName('field_1');
field_1.hidden = true;

const field_2 = this.form.getFieldByName('field_2');
field_2.hidden = true;

const field_3 = this.form.getFieldByName('field_3');
field_3.hidden = true;

const field_4 = this.form.getFieldByName('field_4');
field_4.hidden = true;

const field_5 = this.form.getFieldByName('field_5');
field_5.hidden = true;

const field_5 = this.form.getFieldByName('field_5');
field_5.hidden = true;

Answer (score 41):

**Vue 2**: If you need to know when a component has been `created`, `mounted`, `updated` etc. from a parent component, you can just define a listener using `@hook:` followed by the lifecycle hook name.

E.g. from the parent component to execute `doSomething()` once the child component is mounted:

```js
<child-component @hook:mounted="doSomething" />
```

---

**[2023 UPDATE]**

**Vue 3**: Following the [Vue 2 to Vue 3 migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/vnode-lifecycle-events.html), the event name must now be prefixed with `@vue:`:

```js
<child-component @vue:mounted="doSomething" />
```

Comment: Hey! I read it from a VueDose tip: https://vuedose.tips/listen-to-lifecycle-hooks-on-third-party-vue-js-components/

Comment: In Vue 3, `@hook:` was replaced by `@vnodeXXX`, so it's now `@vnodeMounted="doSomething"` for onMounted, etc. Source:  https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4345

Answer (score 4):

1. Since the child mounting could be delayed more that nextTick(), you can emit an event programatically:

Child JS:

```
{
    mounted: function() {
        this.$emit("mounted");
    }
}
```

Parent HTML:

```
<child @mounted="childMounted">
```

Parent JS:

```
{
    methods: {
        childMounted: function() {
            // TODO child action
        }
    }
}
```

2. An alternative is to use the child component as a mixin
3. Define a directive:

   ```
   Vue.directive("mounted", {
       inserted: function(el, binding) {
           binding.value();
       }
   });
   ```

You don't need to modify the child, only the parent:

Parent HTML:

```
<child v-mounted="childMounted">
```

Parent JS same as in (2)

Answer (score 3):

`mounted()` hook of the parent component does not guarantee that all child component also finish rendering.

To execute something once the whole view has been rendered use `vm.nextTick()` inside the the parent component's `mounted()` hook.

```
//User Registration Vue Component

  mounted(){
    this.$nextTick(()=>{
      //execute your code
      console.log('Finished rendering the complete view')
    })
  }
```

Refer to - [mounted lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted)

---

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried this and received the same issue. I put console.log statements in the input and input options in the mounted function to show when it was finished mounting. I did not enclose these statements in the $nextTick function you showed above. Here is my console output:

Comment: Finished rendering the complete view
input option finsihed mounting
input finsihed mounting
(9) input option finsihed mounting
input finsihed mounting
(8) input option finsihed mounting
input finsihed mounting
(4) input option finsihed mounting
2) input finsihed mounting
(30) input option finsihed mounting
input finsihed mounting
(18) input option finsihed mounting
input finsihed mounting
(7) input option finsihed mounting
(3) input finsihed mounting
(3) input option finsihed mounting
input type finsihed mounting
(7) input finsihed mounting
(3)input option finsihed mounting

Comment: Down-voting because it does not work as expected. Callback fires before all assets are rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Tires, it works well

```
Vue.directive("mounted", {
    inserted: function(el, binding) {
        binding.value();
    }
});
```

Parent:

```
<child v-mounted="childMounted">

{
    methods: {
        childMounted: function() {
            // TODO child action
        }
    }
}
```