# Vue - Why does it take 2 ticks to add component using lazy loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component per file, and I am using lazy loading as indicated here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components

```
  <script>
import Vue from "vue";
export default {
  name: "example",
  components: {
    BaseBlueButton: () => import("@/components/BaseBlueButton"),
    BaseWhiteButton: () => import("@/components/BaseWhiteButton"),
    FloatingHead: () => import("@/components/BaseFloatingHead")
  }, 
  async mounted() { 
    await Vue.nextTick();
    await Vue.nextTick();
    console.log(this.$refs)
    this.$refs.startAvatarButton.$el.focus();
  }
};
</script>
```

In the mounted() function, if I remove one of hte nextTick then the reference is empty.
If I import the component in a regular way, then there is no problem. **WHY ???**

The other way:

```
<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import BaseBlueButton from "@/components/BaseBlueButton";
import BaseWhiteButton from "@/components/BaseWhiteButton";
import FloatingHead from "@/components/BaseFloatingHead";
export default {
  name: "TheUserChoice",
  components: {
    BaseBlueButton,
    BaseWhiteButton,
    FloatingHead
  }, 
  async mounted() { 
    await Vue.nextTick();
    this.$refs.startAvatarButton.$el.focus();
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: This sounds like a good use-case for a [custom directive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html). The example in the docs even uses `focus`

Comment: Most probably the 1st tick (or call it `microtask`) takes care of the component lazy loading. The `mounted` hook of the parent will be called only after `mounted` hooks of ALL children have been called. You can add a listener (as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61460031/5962802) and see when your lazy components are being mounted.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I guessed the same thing, is there any documentation related to this ? I was actually concern with a concurrency issue where not always 2 ticks where enough ( slow networks) but you pointed me in the right direction regarding the listener.

Comment: @Phil thanks, I will refactor that.

Comment: I do not think there is official documentation about your particular case - but you might be able to find a couple of blog posts regarding the parent/child lifecycle hooks.